# Привязать фигуру к курсору, при клике отрисовать в pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, рисование

Всем доброго времени суток, имеется форма на ней `pictureBox1` и пара `textBox`, на pictureBox'е отрисовывается помещение, как можно взять значение из textBox'ов, в которых хранится длина и ширина аппарата, и привязав к курсору нарисовать его в месте, куда кликнем мышью на pictureBox'е?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @ VladD, WinForms

Comment: А в чем проблема? Рисовать уже умеете? Тогда привязываетесь к событию MouseClick или MouseDown, в аргументах есть координаты мыши относительно контрола. По ним и рисуете. Только возьмите лучше обычную Panel для рисования, или даже UserControl. PictureBox для вывода готовых картинок все таки, вам не нужны его дополнительные функции чтобы просто рисовать.

Comment: @ rdorn, разобрался)